# AngularJS get and set value

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to append a signature with date say "Signature 07/08/2015" inside a textarea on a button click. How can I do this is AngularJS way?

Say textarea contains text as "This is a text". After clicking button it should convert to,

```
This is a text
Signature 07/08/2015
```

It's pretty easy to do in JavaScript way, but I am entirely beginner with Angular.

Here is what I have tried to get date in app.js,

```
$scope.getDate = new Date();
```

I can use this in view as,

```
<p ng-bind="getDate | date:'MM/dd/yyyy'"></p>
```

The textarea seems like this,

```
<textarea type="text" class="form-control" id="description" name="description" ng-model="description"></textarea>

<a href="javascript:" id="add-signature" onclick="addSignature();">add signature</a> // this needs to be modify in angular way.
```

Simply in short,

- get textarea value
- append signature
- set this new value in textarea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

**controller**

```
$scope.addSignature=function(){

   $scope.description=$scope.description+ "\nSignature 07/08/2015";
}
```

**View**

```
<a href="javascript:;" id="add-signature" ng-click="addSignature();">add signature</a>
```

Comment: I suppose you mean `$scope.addSignature` instead of `$scope.onClick`?

Comment: @cverb I did the same as you mentioned and this worked. Anik this is amazing and pretty straight forward.